# Find Max Value Of Dictionary Represented As String Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I currently have a table in Postgres like below:

```
|----|---------|-----------------|
| id | field_1 | dict_as_string  | 
|----|---------|-----------------|
|  1 | 7293567 | {'1':62,'2':58} |
|----|---------|-----------------|
|  2 | 7924176 | {'1':32,'2':65} |
|----|---------|-----------------|
|  3 | 7492749 | {'1':12,'2':15} |
|----|---------|-----------------|
|  4 | 5829750 | {'1':34,'2':82} |
|----|---------|-----------------|
```

id type text, field_1 type double_precision, dict_as_string type text

I'm reading this postgres table into a pandas dataframe. What I'm trying to do is create a new column `max` that is the highest value in the dictionary value represented as a string column dict_as_string.

How would I attempt this. I have tried the following:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "table"', con=connection)
df['dict_as_string'] = df['dict_as_string'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df['max'] = max(df['dict_as_string'].values())
```

But this is throwing an error

`TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Is there a way to read this table into pandas, convert dict_as_string values from string to dictionary, then creating a new column with the max value from the converted string that the end product would look like:

```
|----|---------|-----------------|-----|
| id | field_1 | dict_as_string  | max | 
|----|---------|-----------------|-----|
|  1 | 7293567 | {'1':62,'2':58} |  62 |
|----|---------|-----------------|-----|
|  2 | 7924176 | {'1':32,'2':65} |  65 |
|----|---------|-----------------|-----|
|  3 | 7492749 | {'1':12,'2':15} |  15 |
|----|---------|-----------------|-----|
|  4 | 5829750 | {'1':34,'2':82} |  82 |
|----|---------|-----------------|-----|
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# if you haven't applied ast.literal_eval before:
# df['dict_as_string'] = df['dict_as_string'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df["max"] = df["dict_as_string"].apply(lambda x: max(x.values()))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id  field_1      dict_as_string  max
0   1  7293567  {'1': 62, '2': 58}   62
1   2  7924176  {'1': 32, '2': 65}   65
2   3  7492749  {'1': 12, '2': 15}   15
3   4  5829750  {'1': 34, '2': 82}   82
```